# multi-dimensional array possibly

Tags: php, arrays, file-io, multidimensional-array

I have two files that I need opened, I'm using php file to read them

```
$lines = file('/home/program/prog_conf.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
$rows = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
```

Followed by:

```
 $lines = file('/home/domain/public_html/base/file2.cfg');
 foreach ($lines as $line) {
 $rows = preg_split('/=/', $line);
```

As I work with these two files, I need to pull info from the second one, which I seperated by =, however, I'm not sure this is the best thing to do. I wanted to add data checking from the database. The db details are in the second file like so:

```
dbname = databasename
dbuser = databaseuser
dbpass = databasepassword
```

If I echo the $rows[2], I get everything all the information I need on a single line, not on seperate lines. Meaning:

```
databasename databaseuser databasepassword
```

How do I split the information up so I can use the entries one by one?

Comment: Does `parse_ini_file` work on that 2nd file? Also, show that `echo`, aren't you just forgetting to output a newline character? (`"\n"` / `PHP_EOL`), and how are you looking at it? In a browser in HTML mode... it would of course remove newlines for you visually, but they are still there (view source).

Comment: Sidenote: `If` you're using this for DB access, I strongly recommend you either don't use this method, or protect it using `.htaccess` and/or place it out of `public` access.

Comment: I plan on using in the program folder, which is far outside the web fodlers, but as a scheduled cron. Something that'll update the database or file depending on checks I'll add later.

Comment: I haven't done my research or reading on parse_ini_file.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$lines = file('/home/domain/public_html/base/file2.cfg');
$all_parts = array()
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  //explode pulls apart a string based on the first value, so you could change that 
  //to a '=' if need be
  array_merge($all_parts,explode(' ', $line));
}
```

This would get you all the parts of the file, one at a time, into an array. Which is what I think you wanted.

If not, [just explode as needed](https://www.php.net/explode)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this aproach helps:

First as i see your second file has multiple lines, so what would do is something like this:
Assumin that every key as "db" in common we can do something like this.

```
$file = fopen("/home/domain/public_html/base/file2.cfg", "rb");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle); // This function return better performance if the file isn't too large.
fclose($file);

// Assuming this is your return from the file
$contents = 'dbname = databasename dbuser = databaseuser dbpass = databasepassword';

$rows = preg_split('/db+/', $contents); // Splinting keys "db"
$result = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
   $temp = preg_replace("/\s+/", '', $row); // Removing extract white spaces
   $temp = preg_split("/=/", $temp);        // Splinting by "="
   $result[] = $temp[1];                    // Getting the value only
}

var_dump ($result);
```

I hope this help you can try this code maybe with little modifications but works.